# Best way to rewrite array loop logic?

Tags: arrays, vba, loops, logic

```
For i = 0 To n

    If i <= 48 Then 'left section of first page

        signatureSheet.Cells(i + 2, 1) = i + 1
        signatureSheet.Cells(i + 2, 2) = empname(i)
        signatureSheet.Cells(i + 2, 4) = personnum(i)

    ElseIf i <= 97 Or i <= 197 Or i <= 297 Or i <= 397 Then 'right section of first

        signatureSheet.Cells(i - 47, 5) = i + 1
        signatureSheet.Cells(i - 47, 6) = empname(i)
        signatureSheet.Cells(i - 47, 8) = personnum(i)

    ElseIf i <= 147 Or i <= 247 Or i <= 347 Or i <= 497 Then

        signatureSheet.Cells(i - 47, 1) = i + 1
        signatureSheet.Cells(i - 47, 2) = empname(i)
        signatureSheet.Cells(i - 47, 4) = personnum(i)

    End If

Next i
```

This pastes the first 49 of the array in from A2:A50, the next 49 from B2:B50, and the rest in units of fifty in alternating columns from A51:A100, B51:B100, A101:A150, B101:B150 etc. Is there a better way to rewrite this ideally such that it can handle an infinite sized n?

Comment: Call me when you have found a way to copy an infinite number of cells within your lifetime. ;-)  NB: the `if` conditions do not make much sense. Think about those for a while.

Comment: Your code does not do what you say it does. (Nothing like it in fact.)  Your `ElseIf i <= 97 Or i <= 197 Or i <= 297 Or i <= 397 Then` can be simplified to `ElseIf i <= 397 Then` (i.e. any value of `i` which is between 49 and 397) and your `ElseIf i <= 147 Or i <= 247 Or i <= 347 Or i <= 497 Then` can be simplified to `ElseIf i <= 497 Then` (i.e. any value of `i` between 398 and 497).

Answer (score 2):

Friends,
I tried to make the code below.

I would like to know your opinion:

1) About my logic;
2) About naming of variables.
3) On the use of the repetition structure;
4) Do you think I could simplify my logic more?

```
     ' Constants
    Const INITIAL_ROW                    As Long = 2
```

```
' Variables
Dim lngCounter                       As Long
Dim lngInternCounter                 As Long
Dim lngNumberOfReptions              As Long
Dim lngNumberOfRegistersPerReptions  As Long
Dim lngNumberOfFirstField            As Long: lngNumberOfFirstField = 1
Dim lngNumberOfSecondField           As Long: lngNumberOfSecondField = 2
Dim lngNumberOfThirdField            As Long: lngNumberOfThirdField = 3
Dim lngIndexMinArray As Long
Dim lngIndexMaxArray As Long
Dim lngIndexMinAux                   As Long
Dim lngIndexMaxAux                   As Long
Dim lngIndexRowCell                  As Long
```

' .
' .
' .

' Variables Initialize

lngNumberOfRegistersPerReptions = 49 
lngIndexMinArray = LBound(empname, 1)
lngIndexMaxArray = UBound(empname, 1)

If lngIndexMaxArray <= lngNumberOfRegistersPerReptions Then
    lngNumberOfReptions = lngIndexMaxArray + 1

ElseIf lngIndexMinArray = 0 Then
    lngNumberOfReptions = (lngIndexMaxArray + 1) / lngNumberOfRegistersPerReptions

Else
    lngNumberOfReptions = lngIndexMaxArray / lngNumberOfRegistersPerReptions

End If


With signatureSheet
    For lngCounter = 1 To lngNumberOfReptions Step 1
        If lngNumberOfReptions = 1 Then
            lngIndexMinAux = LBound(empname, 1)
            lngIndexMaxAux = UBound(empname, 1)

        ElseIf lngCounter > 0 And lngCounter < lngNumberOfReptions Then
            lngIndexMaxAux = lngCounter * (lngNumberOfRegistersPerReptions - LBound(empname, 1))
            lngIndexMinAux = lngIndexMaxAux - (lngNumberOfRegistersPerReptions - 1)

        Else
            lngIndexMaxAux = lngCounter * (lngNumberOfRegistersPerReptions - LBound(empname, 1))
            lngIndexMinAux = UBound(empname, 1)

        End If

        lngIndexRowCell = INITIAL_ROW
        For lngInternCounter = lngIndexMinAux To lngIndexMaxAux Step 1
            .Cells(lngIndexRowCell, lngNumberOfFirstField).Value = lngInternCounter
            .Cells(lngIndexRowCell, lngNumberOfSecondField).Value = empname(lngInternCounter)
            .Cells(lngIndexRowCell, lngNumberOfThirdField).Value = personnum(lngInternCounter)
            lngIndexRowCell = lngIndexRowCell + 1
        Next lngInternCounter
    Next lngCounter

End With

Answer (score 1):

Maybe if you use `Select Case`, you would notice how redundant your If Statements are.

You are saying

`If i < 10`
- OR -
`If i < 20`
- OR -
`If i <= 30 Then ...`

Which means the exact same thing as

```
If i <= 30
```

> If `i < 10`, then it will *always* be less than 20 and *always* be less than 30.

Try using `Select Case` so you can better understand what your goal is:

```
For i = 0 To n

    Select Case i

        Case 0 To 48

            signatureSheet.Cells(i + 2, 1) = i + 1
            signatureSheet.Cells(i + 2, 2) = empname(i)
            signatureSheet.Cells(i + 2, 4) = personnum(i)

        Case 49 To 397  'Your first 3 i <=... are pointless

            signatureSheet.Cells(i - 47, 5) = i + 1
            signatureSheet.Cells(i - 47, 6) = empname(i)
            signatureSheet.Cells(i - 47, 8) = personnum(i)

        Case 398 To 497 'same with your if line here

            signatureSheet.Cells(i - 47, 1) = i + 1
            signatureSheet.Cells(i - 47, 2) = empname(i)
            signatureSheet.Cells(i - 47, 4) = personnum(i)

        Case Else

            Exit For

    End Select

Next i
```

Comment: Yes, I was (pleasantly) surprised that you fixed it, and immediately up-voted once I saw that you had.